# PHP Combining multidimentional arrays of different lengths

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array, merge

I need to rearrange the following multi-dimensional array to merge and fill in the indexes due to the unknown length of each array. The issue is, is that I don't know in advance how many rows or columns there will need to be if the array is structured wrong.

I first need an array with the strings User Id, Study Id, the Questions from each study in secession, and then the Date. I am not necessarily concerned with this array, for it is pretty simple to create.

Where I am having trouble is that I need an array for each User_Prediction where they contain the same length as the number of questions (does this make sense?). What I am ultimately looking for is to create a CSV file where the heading consists of the UserId, the StudyId and then the combined list of all the questions, and then a date. So, I can take the "desired output" below and simply say for each array fcsvput. If I took the User_Predictions as they are now, they wouldn't line up with the questions when lined up horizontally such as a CSV file.

**Here is a sample array:**

```
[studies] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Study_ID] => 563
            [Questions] => Array
                (
                    [1] => S563 Q1
                    [2] => S563 Q2
                )
            [User_Predictions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [User_ID] => 24
                            [Answers] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 66
                                    [1] => Option 1
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Study_ID] => 510
            [Questions] => Array
                (
                    [1] => S510 Q1
                    [2] => S510 Q2
                    [3] => S510 Q3
                    [4] => S510 Q4
                    [5] => S510 Q5
                )

            [User_Predictions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [User_ID] => 76
                            [Answers] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [1] => 1
                                    [2] => Negative
                                    [3] => 10
                                    [4] => 2,2
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [User_ID] => 58
                            [Answers] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 25
                                    [1] => 20
                                    [2] => Positive
                                    [3] => 5000
                                    [4] => 1,2
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

**And this is what I am looking to achieve:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => User_ID
    [1] => Study_ID
    [2] => S563 Q1 
    [3] => S563 Q2 
    [4] => S510 Q1 
    [5] => S510 Q2 
    [6] => S510 Q3 
    [7] => S510 Q4 
    [8] => S510 Q5 
    [9] => Date
)


Array
(
    [0] => 24
    [1] => 563
    [2] => 66
    [3] => Option 1
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => Date
)


Array
(
    [0] => 76
    [1] => 510
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => Negative
    [7] => 10
    [8] => 2,2
    [9] => Date
)   

Array
(
    [0] => 58
    [1] => 510
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 25
    [5] => 20
    [6] => Positive
    [7] => 5000
    [8] => 1,2
    [9] => Date
)
```

Comment: You can read the code of my implementation of a generalized multi-dimensional array, that might help you to figure it out: https://github.com/Toxyl/multi-dimensional-array/blob/master/MultiDimensionalArray.class.php

Comment: Why is this being down voted?

Comment: @JeffreyKarbowski *"Why is this being down voted?"* .... because your question is unclear (at least for me). I don't understand based on what do you want this desired result? what are `User_ID` and `Study_ID`? constants? strings? I don't see them in the input data. What are the differences between the desired arrays? if you could unclear the question, or explain what are these numbers you could get better results. *I didn't downvote this post BTW*

Comment: Thank you @Accountant I have edited the Sample Array in hopes to clarify these questions. The differences between the sample array and the desired output is that the desired output is a compound of the answers with empty values for missing indexes (if that at all makes sense)م

Comment: Not going to downvote but this doesn't look understandable (at all). You should clearly explain how the output is generated from the input. Either via code comments or any other understandable description.

Comment: @JeyDWork, I have edited more the description in hopes that it becomes more clear. I don't see how this could be difficult, or even have not been attempted before, however, due to my lack of even being able to explain what needs to be done, it becomes difficult to know where to search. I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: The Output you want is not clear. What is user_id and date in the output ?

Comment: Sometimes people downvote questions that show no effort.  If you want to stop the downvotes, I recommend that you post your best failed coding attempt.  Whacking a bounty on a question is not a license to post a "requirements dump".  This community mustn't be abused as a free coding service.

Comment: @JeffreyKarbowski my answer is not good? I think it's clear and requires a few lines of code ...

Comment: @user2342558, I am sure your answer is fine, however Jitendra Yadav was the first to reply and his answer is equally as good. I up voted yours as well.

Comment: I understand, thanks I was curious.

Comment: @michmackusa, I figured that I would try and simplify what I was looking for by keeping the code I used to get to the array that was built out of the question. I don't mean to abuse this community, however I had nowhere to turn and I had no idea what it was going to take to get to the desired result. I searched for days to no avail, and would have been completely happy if I was simply pointedin the direction of "here's where this has been asked before", or "you should be thinking about 'array_key_exists' in your loop". But I didn't get anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Note***: Not sure from where you are getting `date`.

First of all, here is the pattern for your question.

- Every array inside `studies` has a `Study_ID` and a set of questions `Questions` and user predications `User_Predictions` from many users.
- Each prediction has a user `User_ID` and answers to questions from the previous step.
- The `index of question  = index of answer + 1`

**Your Question**: You want each user prediction as a separate array, but it should include all list of questions with their answers if present in that particular study.

**Solution**:

For prediction, it is common that there would be a `Study_ID` and a user who responds to it `User_ID`.

```
// This array will contain all indexes should be present in final array.
$arrIndex   =   ['Study_ID', 'User_ID'];      // Assume these two would always be present, so added in advance.

// This will be temporary array holds data for each user prediction with relevant information i.e. it would not have data for questions which are not in this study.
$arrUserStudy    =   [];

foreach($arr['studies'] as $arrStudy){

    foreach($arrStudy['Questions'] as $strQuestion){
        // To add a new question to the index.
        if(!in_array($strQuestion,  $arrIndex)){
            $arrIndex[] =   $strQuestion;
        }
    }

    foreach($arrStudy['User_Predictions'] as $userStudy){
        $arrTemp  =   [
            'Study_ID'  =>  $arrStudy['Study_ID'],
            'User_ID'   =>  $userStudy['User_ID'],
        ];

        foreach($userStudy['Answers'] as $intKey => $strAnswer){
            $arrTemp[$arrStudy['Questions'][$intKey + 1]]   =   $strAnswer;
        }
        $arrUserStudy[]     =    $arrTemp;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
print_r($arrIndex);

Array
(
    [0] => Study_ID
    [1] => User_ID
    [2] => S563 Q1
    [3] => S563 Q2
    [4] => S510 Q1
    [5] => S510 Q2
    [6] => S510 Q3
    [7] => S510 Q4
    [8] => S510 Q5
)


print_r($arrUserStudy);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Study_ID] => 563
            [User_ID] => 24
            [S563 Q1] => 66
            [S563 Q2] => Option 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Study_ID] => 510
            [User_ID] => 76
            [S510 Q1] => 1
            [S510 Q2] => 1
            [S510 Q3] => Negative
            [S510 Q4] => 10
            [S510 Q5] => 2,2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Study_ID] => 510
            [User_ID] => 58
            [S510 Q1] => 25
            [S510 Q2] => 20
            [S510 Q3] => Positive
            [S510 Q4] => 5000
            [S510 Q5] => 1,2
        )

)
```

If you compare this output with your output, there are only the following differences:

- Each user predication has `key` as question/Study_Id/User_ID but in your output, it is an integer.
- It is missing questions from other studies.

We can easily include missing questions, as we do have all of them in `$arrIndex` and corresponding values would be `null`.

**Changing string keys to integer keys**: I would prefer to go with string keys as even if they are not ordered, you can easily identify and access them with their key_name.

**Final conversion to desired output**:

**Keep string keys and add missing**(preferred):

```
foreach($arrUserStudy as $intKey =>  $userStudy){
    foreach($arrIndex as $strIndex){
        if(!array_key_exists($strIndex, $userStudy)){
            $arrUserStudy[$intKey][$strIndex] = null;
        }
    }
}

print_r($arrUserStudy);

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Study_ID] => 563
            [User_ID] => 24
            [S563 Q1] => 66
            [S563 Q2] => Option 1
            [S510 Q1] => 
            [S510 Q2] => 
            [S510 Q3] => 
            [S510 Q4] => 
            [S510 Q5] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Study_ID] => 510
            [User_ID] => 76
            [S510 Q1] => 1
            [S510 Q2] => 1
            [S510 Q3] => Negative
            [S510 Q4] => 10
            [S510 Q5] => 2,2
            [S563 Q1] => 
            [S563 Q2] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Study_ID] => 510
            [User_ID] => 58
            [S510 Q1] => 25
            [S510 Q2] => 20
            [S510 Q3] => Positive
            [S510 Q4] => 5000
            [S510 Q5] => 1,2
            [S563 Q1] => 
            [S563 Q2] => 
        )

)
```

Note: Here you see that keys are not ordered but you can just loop over `$arrIndex` and can access key at any place by `$arrUserStudy[<loop_variable>][<index_name>]`.

**Convert to integer keys and add missing**:

```
$arrReindexed   =   [];
foreach($arrUserStudy as $intKey =>  $userStudy){
    $arrTemp    =   [];
    foreach($arrIndex as $intKey =>  $strIndex){
        $arrTemp[$intKey]   =   array_key_exists($strIndex, $userStudy) ?  $userStudy[$strIndex] : null;
    }

    $arrReindexed[]     =   $arrTemp;
}

print_r($arrReindexed);

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 563
            [1] => 24
            [2] => 66
            [3] => Option 1
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 510
            [1] => 76
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [6] => Negative
            [7] => 10
            [8] => 2,2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 510
            [1] => 58
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 25
            [5] => 20
            [6] => Positive
            [7] => 5000
            [8] => 1,2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a relative simple solution to get your desired result.

*Some clarifications are at the end of this post.*

This is the array of input data:

```
$studiesData = Array
(
    "0" => Array
    (
        "Study_ID" => "563",
        "Questions" => Array
        (
            "1" => "S563 Q1",
            "2" => "S563 Q2"
        ),
        "User_Predictions" => Array
        (
            "0" => Array
            (
                "User_ID" => "24",
                "Answers" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "66",
                    "1" => "Option 1"
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    "1" => Array
    (
        "Study_ID" => "510",
        "Questions" => Array
        (
            "1" => "S510 Q1",
            "2" => "S510 Q2",
            "3" => "S510 Q3",
            "4" => "S510 Q4",
            "5" => "S510 Q5"
        ),
        "User_Predictions" => Array
        (
            "0" => Array
            (
                "User_ID" => "76",
                "Answers" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "1",
                    "1" => "1",
                    "2" => "Negative",
                    "3" => "10",
                    "4" => "2,2"
                )
            ),
            "1" => Array
            (
                "User_ID" => "58",
                "Answers" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "25",
                    "1" => "20",
                    "2" => "Positive",
                    "3" => "5000",
                    "4" => "1,2"
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Fix the array's indexes to get them all with an ordered key:

```
foreach ($studiesData as $k => &$studyData)
{
    $studyData['Questions'] = array_values($studyData['Questions']);
    foreach ($studyData['User_Predictions'] as $k2 => &$responses)
    {
        $responses['Answers'] = array_values($responses['Answers']);
    }
    unset($responses); // break the reference with the last element
}
unset($studyData); // break the reference with the last element
```

Now the array `$studiesData` is:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($studiesData);
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Study_ID] => 563
            [Questions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => S563 Q1
                    [1] => S563 Q2
                )

            [User_Predictions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [User_ID] => 24
                            [Answers] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 66
                                    [1] => Option 1
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Study_ID] => 510
            [Questions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => S510 Q1
                    [1] => S510 Q2
                    [2] => S510 Q3
                    [3] => S510 Q4
                    [4] => S510 Q5
                )

            [User_Predictions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [User_ID] => 76
                            [Answers] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [1] => 1
                                    [2] => Negative
                                    [3] => 10
                                    [4] => 2,2
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [User_ID] => 58
                            [Answers] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 25
                                    [1] => 20
                                    [2] => Positive
                                    [3] => 5000
                                    [4] => 1,2
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Store all questions in a dedicated array that we'll use later for convenience:

```
$totalQuestions = array();
foreach ($studiesData as $k => $studyData)
{
    foreach ($studyData['User_Predictions'] as $responses)
    {
        foreach ($studyData['Questions'] as $questionDescription)
        {
            $totalQuestions[$questionDescription] = $questionDescription;
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($totalQuestions);
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
    [S563 Q1] => S563 Q1
    [S563 Q2] => S563 Q2
    [S510 Q1] => S510 Q1
    [S510 Q2] => S510 Q2
    [S510 Q3] => S510 Q3
    [S510 Q4] => S510 Q4
    [S510 Q5] => S510 Q5
)
```

Generate the resulting array with the desired format:

```
$result2 = array();
$result2[0][] = 'User_ID';
$result2[0][] = 'Study_ID';
$x = 1;
foreach($studiesData as $k => $studyData)
{
    foreach ($studyData['User_Predictions'] as $k2 => $userData)
    {
        $x++;
        $result2[$x][0] = $userData['User_ID'];
        $result2[$x][1] = $studyData['Study_ID'];

        foreach($totalQuestions as $questionDescription)
        {
            if(!in_array($questionDescription, $result2[0]))
            {
                $result2[0][] = $questionDescription;
            }

            if(($idQuestion = array_search($questionDescription, $studyData['Questions'])) !== false)
            {
                $result2[$x][] = $userData['Answers'][$idQuestion];
            }
            else
            {
                $result2[$x][] = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result2);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Final output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => User_ID
            [1] => Study_ID
            [2] => S563 Q1
            [3] => S563 Q2
            [4] => S510 Q1
            [5] => S510 Q2
            [6] => S510 Q3
            [7] => S510 Q4
            [8] => S510 Q5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [1] => 563
            [2] => 66
            [3] => Option 1
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 76
            [1] => 510
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [6] => Negative
            [7] => 10
            [8] => 2,2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 58
            [1] => 510
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 25
            [5] => 20
            [6] => Positive
            [7] => 5000
            [8] => 1,2
        )
)
```

*Some clarifications*:

- [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.
- [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) after the foreach: as the documentation says:

> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the
>   foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

- [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful.

The `!==` check for `false` is needed because this function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.

**`Date`**: you have the `Date` entry in your final output in your question, but it there isn't in the array input. If you update your question I'll include it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to cut this down so there are as few steps as possible.

This divides it into 2 stages, gather the data and then format the output.  I've added comments to the code as it helps explaining things in context of the code...

```
$entries = [];
$fields = ['User_ID' => null, 'Study_ID' => null];
// Input array of values is $data
foreach ( $data as $study ) {
    $studyOptions = [];
    foreach ( $study["Questions"] as $question )    {
        // Add questions to list of possibilities
        $fields[$question] = null;
        // Keep a list of the options for this question
        $studyOptions[] = $question;
    }
    foreach ( $study["User_Predictions"] as $prediction )   {
        $userData = ["User_ID" => $prediction["User_ID"],
            "Study_ID" => $study["Study_ID"]];
        // For each prediction, use the corresponding $studyOptions entry to set a field
        // with the prediction for this question
        foreach ( $prediction["Answers"] as $key => $value )   {
            $userData[$studyOptions[$key]] = $value;
        }
        // Add this to the list of data so far
        $entries[] = $userData;
    }
}
```

To show some of the data so far...

```
print_r($entries[0]);
// First row of data example
// Array
// (
//     [User_ID] => 24
//     [Study_ID] => 563
//     [S563 Q1] => 66
//     [S563 Q2] => Option 1
// )

print_r($fields);
// List of fields to be used in final output
// Array
// (
//     [User_ID] =>
//     [Study_ID] =>
//     [S563 Q1] =>
//     [S563 Q2] =>
//     [S510 Q1] =>
//     [S510 Q2] =>
//     [S510 Q3] =>
//     [S510 Q4] =>
//     [S510 Q5] =>
//     )
```

Finally format the output

```
$output = [array_keys($fields)];
foreach ( $entries as $entry )   {
    // Use array_replace - to create an entry with all $fields values 
    // from the current entry, use array_values to remove keys
    $output[] = array_values(array_replace($fields, $entry));
}
```

Gives..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => User_ID
            [1] => Study_ID
            [2] => S563 Q1
            [3] => S563 Q2
            [4] => S510 Q1
            [5] => S510 Q2
            [6] => S510 Q3
            [7] => S510 Q4
            [8] => S510 Q5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [1] => 563
            [2] => 66
            [3] => Option 1
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
        )
....
```